# How to extract money value and currency from narratives which have different format and type of currency?

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract money value and its currency from a column of narratives.
However, formats of currency in narratives are messy.

I've tried gsub() but don't know how to customize it to deal with difference cases.

Input:

```
words <- c("sold for USD 8.5 in cash in Nov. 2005", 
           "bought in Dec. 2012 for approx. $130", 
           "sold for GBP 11 on 03/03/2010", 
           "bought for EUR 33 in cash")
```

Expected output:

```
value <- c(8.5, 130, 11, 33)
currency <- c("USD", "USD", "GBP", "EUR")
```

Comment: Unless someone already wrote a package for it. You need to use regular expression to match the currency type and amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strapply` extracts the matches to the capture groups (i.e. parenthesized portions of pattern) of the pattern `pat` from the character strings `word` (first argument) and inputs the capture groups as separate arguments to the function (third argument -- the function may be expressed in formula notation with the body of the function on the right hand side of the tilde).  It returns the output of the function.

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "(USD|GBP|EUR|\\$) *([0-9.]+)"
currency <- strapply(words, pat, ~ sub("\\$", "USD", ..1), simplify = TRUE)
value <- strapply(words, pat, ~ as.numeric(..2), simplify = TRUE)
```

Comment: I got an error using this method:  Error in if (nchar(s) > 0 && substring(s, 1, 1) == "\002") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: The code in the answer with `words` from the question works for me. In general, when you face an error message in R showing the text of the error message is rarely sufficient to determine what the problem is. In general, you need to explain exactly how someone else can reproduce the error message. First try copying and pasting `words` from the question into a fresh R session and then copy and paste the code from the answer above. If that works then we don't know what you did to get the error so please explain it in a reproducible way.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) and `str_extract_all()` from the `stringr` package (part of the `tidyverse`).

The first issue is that you have a dollar sign, which is not an explicit currency. If you want to assume that the dollar sign is **USD** - and there may be other examples, such as the pound sign, etc. - then perhaps as a first step you can do a little cleaning on the source text, by simply replacing occurrences of "$" with "USD":

```
words <- c("sold for USD 8.5 in cash in Nov. 2005", 
           "bought in Dec. 2012 for approx. $130", 
           "sold for GBP 11 on 03/03/2010", 
           "bought for EUR 33 in cash")

words <- str_replace_all(words, "\\$", "USD")
```

Then create a character vector of valid currencies, which you can add to as necessary:

```
currencies <- c("USD", "GBP", "EUR")
```

Then set up your regular expressions:

```
regexCurrency <- paste0("(", paste0(currencies, collapse = "|"), ")")
## [1] "(USD|GBP|EUR)"
```

The above will find any of the valid currencies.

```
regexAmount <- "[0-9\\.]+"
```

The above will find any numeric value including an optional decimal point.

Then extract all valid currency/value pairs (i.e. ignore numeric values that do not follow a currency, e.g. the year "2005"):

```
x <- str_extract_all(words, paste0(regexCurrency, " *", regexAmount))
[[1]]
[1] "USD 8.5"

[[2]]
[1] "USD130"

[[3]]
[1] "GBP 11"

[[4]]
[1] "EUR 33"
```

Then use the currency and amount regular expressions to generate separate vectors for value and currency:

```
value <- str_extract_all(x, regexAmount) %>% unlist %>% as.numeric
## [1]   8.5 130.0  11.0  33.0

currency <- str_extract_all(, regexCurrency) %>% unlist
## [1] "USD" "USD" "GBP" "EUR"
```

You may need to consider other situations, such as currencies being in a different case, or numeric values containing commas. These can be accounted for by amending the regular expressions as required.

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can first change `$` to `USD` with `gsub`. Then extract matches for `currency` and `values` with a `regex` using `regexpr` and `regmatches`. Now form this matches you can extract `value` and `currency` again with `gsub`.

```
tt <- gsub("\\$", "USD", words)
tt <- regmatches(tt, regexpr("\\b(USD|GBP|EUR) *[0-9.]+", tt))
(value <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", tt)))
#[1]   8.5 130.0  11.0  33.0
(currency <- gsub("[0-9. ]", "", tt))
#[1] "USD" "USD" "GBP" "EUR"
```